# JD GUI decompiler is not working through any other file open method other than drag and drop on mac

Tags: java, decompiler

JD GUI decompiler is not working through any other file open method other than drag and drop on mac when I am trying to open a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue for Java Decompiler JD-GUI.

Below, a solution that I found, working for me.

> I found that there is something about security policy which prohibits
> jd-gui from accessing certain directory structures, like ~/Documents
> for example. It will not see any directory structure beyond it. If I
> copy the file structure I want to examine into another accessible dir,
> like /tmp/ then I am able to browse.

Source: https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/issues/335.